# batch list net view and write their ip address to a variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, ip-address

I basically need a script (batch) that automatically converts the users on the local network to IP addresses.  What I mean is basically set every user that shows up in the command "net view" to a different variable, for example:

If I had 4 different users on the network, I would need the file to list:

```
1: (%1%)
2: (%2%)
3: (%3%)
4: (%4%)
```

So I need the script to set each user on the network to a different variable (starting at 1)

Also...

How would I set the local IP address of each computer name as a variable?

update for second part:  I need to know how to set the ip address as a variable.  I just need to cut out the excess stuff.  If I type

```
 ping (computername) -4
```

I get:  well, I guess it is just easier to show you...

[image: using ping]

I think I need to use the findstr command, but I don't know.

Comment: Does the net view command actually return the IP of each computer listed? How would you get the data that you want to assign to these variables?

Comment: no it doesn't. It tells you the computername.  but you can then type in [code](ping computername) `code` and in parentheses it says: "pinging 192.168.1.9 with x bytes", so I basically need to extract just the IP address from the ping -4 command (-4 means ipv4 address)

Comment: When pinging a local computer on the network it will sometimes return an IPv6 address and at others an IPv4, is this a problem for you?

Comment: In windows 8, half the time it gives you a mac address, so I add -4 to the end, to only show IPv4.

Comment: Can you show a sample `net view` screen so we can see what you are seeing in Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('net view') do (
  set comp=%%a & set comp=!comp:\\=!
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%b in (
    'ping -4 !comp!'
  ) do (Echo !comp! - %%b)
)
```