# How to get names of devices in your local network using node js

Tags: node.js

I need to get HueBridge IP address in my app in node js, I would like to scan the whole network and then search for the name "Hue Bridge" or something similar, I found npm package named 'local-devices', but it doesn't return a device name for me for some reason.

```
const find = require('local-devices');

find().then(devices => {
    console.log(devices)
  })
```

Output:

```
[
  { name: '?', ip: '192.168.1.72', mac: 'secret_mac'},
  { name: '?', ip: '192.168.1.116', mac: 'secret_mac'},
  { name: '?', ip: '192.168.1.117', mac: 'secret_mac'}
]
```

Comment: This package relies entirelly on `arp` command, and `arp` command behaves differently for windows and linux/unix. arp for Windows does not return names, for example, and if you check the [sources of this package for windows parser part](https://github.com/DylanPiercey/local-devices/blob/master/src/parser/win32.js) - you will notice that `name` will be "?" all the time.

Comment: Thank you so much, did not think about it. So is there a way to return a name using something else? There must be since software like ipscanner returns a name on windows

Comment: I tried to seek a bit the solution for your issue, but nothing really interesting appeared. In worst case, you can implement your own analog of the lib you tried to use, to try to execute windows cmd and parse a result from it. Using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/602738/what-is-windows-command-to-convert-machine-name-to-ip-address-and-vice-versa) commands for example.

Comment: Here is another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896263/batch-list-net-view-and-write-their-ip-address-to-a-variable)
Not sure if there is any npm lib for that.